# Cannot "step into" or see definition/docs for required modules in app.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, botframework

I have a Node.js Bot Builder project with the main app code in TypeScript i.e. app.ts. Whereas I get code completion and step into code of modules I have required like 'botbuilder' in the transpiled app.js, I cannot do so in app.ts.

I have tried including the paths in tsconfig.json, but doesn't seem to help:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "inlineSourceMap": true,
  "inlineSources": true,
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "botbuilder": ["node_modules/botbuilder/lib/"]
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your import statement look like? `import * as botbuilder from "botbuilder";` should work in your TypeScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using your tsconfig.json:

```
import * as  builder from "botbuilder";
import * as restify from 'restify';

var server = restify.createServer(); //breakpoint here
```

Once breakpoint is hit, `Step Into` correctly steps into /node_modules/restify/lib/index.js:

[image]

Note that `Do not step into library scripts` has to be turned off in `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping`